# Azure cloud doesn't seem reliable or Application StockTrader buggy?

Tags: asp.net, azure

I tested MSDN StockTrader5 online and it doesn't work
https://azurestocktrader.cloudapp.net/Quotes.aspx?symbols=s:100;s:101;s:102;s:103

what's the cause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working now...

My guess is that this might have been a genuine outage - but it's impossible from here to tell whether it was caused by an incorrect application upgrade or by an outage within SQL Azure.

Overall, I've found Azure and SQL Azure to be very reliable, but obviously when a someone comes along and sees an error in an online showcase then it's not a good first impression for them.

Comment: I checked that's true it's now working (the guy must be a stackoverflow reader :))

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the error message:

`Login failed for user 'trade'.`

It looks like this application is trying to login to the MSSQL database using a username/password that isn't correct.  It looks to be a simple configuration error.

Comment: Well it is supposed to be a demo they should at least care about that pff :)

Comment: Even big corporations can suffer from finger trouble